# Window.open works only once in safari browser

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, window.open

I am trying to download canvas image on new tab in safari browser.
It only works first time click, after that doesn't responds.
But it works if the content type is text or json, problem with image/png or pdf content type.

Below is my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64;");
window.open(img,"");
```

I have been googling this issue from last 3 days, i hope somebody can help me here!!!

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Use an unique name for the window instead of an empty string.

Comment: @Teemu tried with that too didnt worked

Comment: Not related to your issue, but your option to `toDataURL()` is not correct, only the MIME Type should be there, but you're lucky since it will default to `'image/png'`.

Comment: @Kaiido canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); did this still same issue

Comment: Yep I said it's not related. For your issue, I can't repro on my Safari.